# Select week day names for the time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have time interval, and I want my query to output a table with one column `Days` which is going to have all days of week in that interval in the natural order so if the interval is bigger than a week (i.e. between '2014-2-1' and '2014-2-21'), the result would be:

```
Day
----
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
```

If the interval starts, lets say on Friday and ends on the following Monday (i.e. between '2014-2-21' and '2014-2-24'), the output will be:

```
Day
----
Sunday
Monday
Friday
Saturday
```

Comment: Can you show the sample data that you want to result in the above outputs?  As well as what you've tried so far.

Comment: @GoatCO Sample is there. And what I have tried? I understand how to do it using cursor. But I need something noniterative, using datename(dw, ...) or datepart(dw,...) And I'm stuck with the question, how to supply the date interval instead of just one date.

Comment: How on earth do you get the output in your second example? I'd expect Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt natural order is "Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the following approach:

- generate a row for each day in your range (with ROW_NUMBER())
- get the weekday for each generated row (using datename(weekday, ..) )
- get the numeric weekday (using @@datefirst / datepart)

SQL:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20140221'
  , @EndDate DATE = '20140224'

SELECT 
  datename(weekday, v1.day) as weekday, 
  (((@@datefirst-1) + datepart(weekday, v1.day)) % 7) as weekday_num,
  v1.day FROM (
  SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) AS day
  FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
            FROM      sys.columns c
          ) nbrs
  WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
) v1
order by 2
```

UPDATE
To correctly handle the case with more than 7 days, you can wrap it in another `SELECT` with `DISTINCT`:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20140221'
  , @EndDate DATE = '20140224'
SELECT DISTINCT weekday, weekday_num FROM (
SELECT 
  datename(weekday, v1.day) as weekday, 
  (((@@datefirst-1) + datepart(weekday, v1.day)) % 7) as weekday_num,
  v1.day FROM (
  SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) AS day
  FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
            FROM      sys.columns c
          ) nbrs
  WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
) v1

) v2 order by 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ef67/10)

Comment: That one does not give the right answer for longer intervals

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of DatePart and DateName to do this.  You can get your date like this:

```
select datename(dw,getdate()) --Friday

select datepart(dw,getdate()) --6
```

Just substitute **getdate()** (which would return today's date) with your field name.  Then, you can display DateName but sort by DatePart.

Comment: The thing is I need it for the interval, not just for one date

Comment: So select *, datename(dw,YourDateField), datepart(dw,YourDateField) from YourTable where YourDateField > OneDate and YourDateField < OtherDate.